# Why alerts are not stopping?

Tags: reactjs

```
<CardActions onClick={
         this.state.latitude ?
         (async () => {
                 await CustomDialog(<MapDialog
                        points={[
                               { lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude },
                               { lat: item.provLat, lng: item.provLng }
                        ]}
                  />, {
                  title: 'Routing',
                  showCloseIcon: true,
                  });
           })
           :
           alert("Please allow to access your location")
      <IconButton id='btn' className='button'>Show Path</IconButton>
</CardActions>
```

This `<CardActions>` in a `<Card>` component from material ui.
When {this.state.latitude} is false, why the alert appears without even clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you should pass a function to your `onClick` property. Here, instead of passing a function you are invoking `alert`. This way your `alert` triggers, and your `onClick` doesn't work because `alert()` returns an undefined value to it.

so you should pass a function at second part of your ternary operator like:

```
() => alert("Please allow to access your location")
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` is an event handler that is used to fire `functions`, instead of simply alerting the message, you should call a `function` over there

```
<CardActions onClick={
         this.state.latitude ?
         (async () => {
                 await CustomDialog(<MapDialog
                        points={[
                               { lat: this.state.latitude, lng: this.state.longitude },
                               { lat: item.provLat, lng: item.provLng }
                        ]}
                  />, {
                  title: 'Routing',
                  showCloseIcon: true,
                  });
           })
           :
           (
             () => alert("Please allow to access your location")
           )
      <IconButton id='btn' className='button'>Show Path</IconButton>
</CardActions>
```

Your onClick method looks soo rushy, it's better to make another function and call that function if the ternary operator returns true.